# Difference between /dev/i2c-1 and device file for specific device

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, i2c

I am new to embedded Linux and trying to wrap my head around the concept of Linux device driver. I can see device file for each i2c bus on my system i.e. */dev/i2c-x*. I am trying to understand if I write a driver for a specific device connected to a i2c bus, say i2c-1 then the driver will create a device file for that device as well. So the question is, what's the difference between device file */dev/i2c-x* and the device file which is created by the device specific driver? Also, is it possible to access the device on i2c bus via the */dev/i2c-x* device file? If yes, then what's the need of creating Linux driver specific to the i2c device connected on that bus?

Comment: You mixed several things together: **1)** device driver for i2c slave, **2)** special device node created by the device driver (usually character device), **3)** _user space_ "driver" for i2c slave versus _kernel_ driver. I suggest to first understand the difference between these three concepts and then come again with more granular questions (which are actually close to offtopic on SO).

Comment: "*what's the difference between ...*" -- The former device node is for the I2C *master* controller and its bus, and the latter device node is for an I2C *slave* device. "*is it possible to access the device ...*" -- Yes, there is a kludge mechanism that allows access to I2C slave devices as well as report responses to bus addresses. "*what's the need of creating ...*" -- ***Hardware abstraction***. Remove details of the HW from user application code for portability, and make the kernel resolve I2C bus contention. E.G. why does user code need to know/provide the I2C bus address?